# STSでRooをインストール時、リポジトリの読み取り失敗

Tags: java, spring

Spring Roo初心者です。STSにRooをインストールしようしたんですが、STSで以下のエラーが出ました。どうもリポジトリからダウンロード失敗のようです。

どうすればいいでしょうか、誠に恐縮ですが、教えていただけたら大変助かります。

Problems occurred while performing installation: Unable to read repository at https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/extensions/sts380/c...
Unable to read repository at https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/extensions/sts380/c...
peer not authenticated

Answer (score -1):

ネットワーク接続をネイティブからマニアルに変更してもダメでした。

Comment: もしかして、質問者の方と同じ方でしょうか？　質問に対する補足は質問を直接編集することで行えますが、アカウントが分かれてしまうとすぐには行えないため回答欄に書くしかなかったのではないかと推測しています。もしアカウントが2つになってしまった場合、[こちらのヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を参考にアカウント統合を行えます。回答になっていない回答はその内削除されてしまうため、どうぞご検討くださいませ。

Comment: 編集リクエストありがとうございます！　しかし、質問の内容に触れるような編集は基本的に質問者さん本人のアカウントでしかできないことになっています。まずはアカウントの統合をお待ち頂ければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 二つアカウントではないです！補足書こうとしたら、場所見つからなかったのです。